# Split string in a new line after the N word

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a long string, want to break that string in new line after a predefined word count.

My string is look like:

> A string is a data type used in programming, such as an integer and floating point unit, but is used to represent text rather than numbers. It is comprised of a set of characters that can also contain spaces and numbers.

I want to split in to new line this string after a 50 character.

Comment: Split after word or character count? Which one is it?

Comment: Uh, how do you plan on splitting after both 50 characters and 50 words? That makes no sense.

Comment: Split your string into an array of strings, start adding them to a StringBuilder until you're next string you're adding pushes you over the 50 char limit. When that happens, add a \n and continue.

Comment: @ttymatty: split from 50 word

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string text = "A string is a data type used in programming, such as an integer and floating point unit, but is used to represent text rather than numbers. It is comprised of a set of characters that can also contain spaces and numbers.";

int startFrom = 50;
var index = text.Skip(startFrom)
                .Select((c, i) => new { Symbol = c, Index = i + startFrom })
                .Where(c => c.Symbol == ' ')
                .Select(c => c.Index)
                .FirstOrDefault();


if (index > 0)
{
    text = text.Remove(index, 1)
        .Insert(index, Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: I envy those that are able to use .NET 3.5+... however the readability on that is painful.

Comment: Not agree regarding readability, perhaps you not used LINQ often so this is unusual for you

Comment: He is using Linq and Lambdas to do some powerful work in very terse code. The compiler and frameworks is doing tons of work for him. You very well should envy these 1337 skillz.

Comment: @sll not usual, just envy the fact I can't use it at work. The Formatting was the issue with readability, but that is resolved now. nice answer.

Comment: @Ryan Ternier : sorry I've not get point regarding formatting from the first comment. Why you can not port your work project from .NET 2.0 to 3.5? I understand sometimes management argue to do not spend costly time for such things, ot this is not a problem?

Comment: Politics, tax payer money, BizTalk, Java, JNBridge, DB2, IBM MainFrame... too many reasons why the move up would be bad. We've tried, but there's too many dependencies built into the system. Moving it to a newer version of code wouldn't give the province the benifit:cost required for the change.

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, you could easily accomplish splitting after *50 characters* for this in a simple for:

```
    string s = "A string is a data type used in programming, such as an integer and floating point unit, but is used to represent text rather than numbers. It is comprised of a set of characters that can also contain spaces and numbers.";
    List<string> strings = new List<string>();
    int len = 50;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 50)
    {
        if (i + 50 > s.Length)
        {
            len = s.Length - i;
        }
        strings.Add(s.Substring(i,len));
    }
```

Your result being held in `strings`.

Comment: Why not use a StringBuilder so he can .ToString() it?

Comment: @Ryan He could just do, `strings.Aggregate((i, j) => i + Environment.NewLine + j)` if he wanted it in a formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string thestring = "A string is a data type used in programming, such as an integer and floating point unit, but is used to represent text rather than numbers. It is comprised of a set of characters that can also contain spaces and numbers.";
        string sSplitted = string.Empty; 
        while (thestring.Length > 50)
        {
            sSplitted += thestring.Substring(1, 50) + "\n";
            thestring = thestring.Substring(50, (thestring.Length-1) -50);
        }
        sSplitted += thestring;
```